# BLE device works on ios but not on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Here's my problem
I have an electronic lock that uses BLE, it works fine on ios(Both LightBlue & the app I made)
But on Android, after bonding with the lock(I entered the pin code 000000), I can connect to the device, but one of the Service (UUID:7570) becomes empty, and I can't read or write to any characteristic.
Also the device always gets disconnected after about 20 seconds.

This is the ScreenShot from ios

[image]

This is the ScreenShot from android (with empty Service)

[image]

Here's the log I got from nRF Connect

```
nRF Connect, 2018-02-07          
OHGA-ELock 60012 (68:C9:0B:15:99:0D)          
V   17:57:52.234    Connecting to 68:C9:0B:15:99:0D...          
D   17:57:52.234    gatt = device.connectGatt(autoConnect = false, TRANSPORT_LE)          
D   17:57:52.767    [Callback] Connection state changed with status: 0 and new state: CONNECTED (2)          
I   17:57:52.767    Connected to 68:C9:0B:15:99:0D          
D   17:57:52.769    wait(1600ms)          
D   17:57:52.785    [Broadcast] Action received: android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED          
V   17:57:54.373    Discovering services...          
D   17:57:54.373    gatt.discoverServices()          
D   17:57:54.395    [Callback] Services discovered with status: 0          
I   17:57:54.395    Services discovered          
V   17:57:54.414    Generic Access (0x1800)          
- Device Name [R] (0x2A00)          
- Appearance [R] (0x2A01)          
- Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters [R] (0x2A04)          
Generic Attribute (0x1801)          
Unknown Service (00007570-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)          
Device Information (0x180A)          
- System ID [R] (0x2A23)          
- Model Number String [R] (0x2A24)          
- Serial Number String [R] (0x2A25)          
- Firmware Revision String [R] (0x2A26)          
- Hardware Revision String [R] (0x2A27)          
- Software Revision String [R] (0x2A28)          
- Manufacturer Name String [R] (0x2A29)  

D   17:58:10.701    [Callback] Connection state changed with status: 8 and new state: DISCONNECTED (0)  
        E   17:58:10.701    Error 8 (0x8): GATT CONN TIMEOUT   
        I   17:58:10.701    Disconnected  
        D   17:58:10.794    [Broadcast] Action received: android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
```

I've tested it on different Android phones with different testing apps.
Is there a chance this is an issue of the BLE device?

Please let me know if more specific details are needed.
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to describe exactly what happens and preferably show your code. With "can't read/write", do you mean you can't discover the services, the readCharacteristic/writeCharacteristic operations return false or that the callbacks aren't called at all? Or something else? If you use nRF Connect, please post the log from it.

Comment: @Emil Thanks for the advice! I've edited my post

Comment: If it disconnects due to timeout (8), it's a problem with the radio or interference, and not a coding problem. If a service is empty when it shouldn't be, it's probably incorrectly set up at the GATT server.

Comment: i also faced the `empty Service` issue in android. In my case i just refreshed the services from `nrf connect` and it solved my problem. Try it maybe it will help you out too.

Answer (score 0):

> the device always gets disconnected after about 20 seconds

This is because of the **supervision timeout**. In Android it is hardcoded to 20 seconds during which a re-connect doesn’t work. For more information to know what this 20 seconds and supervision timeout take a look here- [Android BLE connection timeouts and GATT internal errors](https://blog.classycode.com/a-short-story-about-android-ble-connection-timeouts-and-gatt-internal-errors-fa89e3f6a456)